# How can I get the mouse cursor type in windows (default, hand, wait, resize etc)?

Tags: windows, winapi

I would like to receive a notification when the mouse cursor change from arrow to hour glass etc.

Until now I managed to get notified for mouse position change events, but I can not figure out how to get the cursor type. It looks like the PCURSORINFO struct does not contain any information about the cursor type.

This is the code I have until now:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WinEventCallback(_In_ int nCode,
                                          _In_ WPARAM wParam,
                                          _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    PCURSORINFO curInfo;
    curInfo->cbSize = sizeof(curInfo);
    GetCursorInfo(curInfo);
}    

void MouseCursorHook::setMouseCursorHook()
    {

        HHOOK evntHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,
                                                   WinEventCallback,
                                                   GetModuleHandle(0),
                                                   0

                        );      
    }
```

Comment: As any application is free to use a custom cursor (and many do), what cursor type would you expect to get for them? Most applications don't care what the current cursor type is; when you want to change the cursor, you store the current one, set the one you want instead, and then when you're finished you set it back to the original one, and *current* and *new* and *original* are all cursors you've established yourself. I'm not aware of any global functionality to retrieve the *current* one, as there can be dozens of *current* ones, one for each windowed control.

Comment: @KenWhite I would like to get the Windows build in cursor type that is currently visible, even when no other windows are loaded, just the windows desktop for example. I have seen that there are some constants like IDC_HAND, IDC_ARROW, defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391(v=vs.85).aspx .

Comment: Title and question body ask about different things. What do you really need? And while this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), please also explain, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: @IInspectable I am asking about if there is a way to get a notification from Windows OS when the mouse cursor type changes. If this is not possible, what is the best way to get the cursor type. And I provided some code related to what I have done so far.

Comment: You haven't answered, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, though. That's important to understand, to know, whether you are implementing an appropriate solution, or have gone the wrong way.

Comment: @IInspectable my question is clear, It is not a XY problem. The answers from Ken and Remy pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: No one claimed, that the question were unclear. It could still be an XY Problem. But since you never answered the question, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, no one can help you with that. And you may be left with a less than optimal solution. That's your decision, though.

Comment: @IInspectable What do you mean "what I am ultimately trying to accomplish?" I told you 2 times what I am ultimately trying to accomplish: get the mouse cursor type and a mouse cursor type change notification if it exists.

Comment: Another way to put it: What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: @IInspectable I am going to send the mouse cursor type to an other machine using sockets.

Comment: This isn't what you are ultimately using the information for, though, and the answer you accepted will not *reliably* return the cursor type anyway (e.g. if an application dynamically creates a cursor by calling `CreateCursor` or `LoadCursorFromFile`). This is not at all uncommon.

Comment: @IInspectable No, this is what I am ultimately using the information for. Remy and Ken understood the question and gave me a quick and correct answer.

Comment: This is inconclusive. If indeed all you do with the information is to hand it off, and no one is interested in dealing with it, you might as well not hand it off altogether. The observable effect is the same. If, on the other hand, that other process, running on another machine, does process the information, what is that process using the information for? I'm not trying to harass you. I'm just asking you to produce a clear problem statement, so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your call to `GetCursorInfo()` is wrong. You are passing it an uninitialized pointer. It should be like this instead:

```
CURSORINFO curInfo = {};
curInfo.cbSize = sizeof(curInfo);
GetCursorInfo(&curInfo);
```

Second, `CURSORINFO` has a `hCursor` field.  You can compare that against the return value of `LoadCursor()`/`LoadImage()` to see if a standard cursor is being used or not.  You will have to compare each standard cursor individually, though.